# How to stub angular-translate promise and verify actions in 'then'

Tags: angularjs, promise, sinon, angular-translate

I'm translating an app with angular-translate, but having trouble fixing up my test suite.

Before - controller looked like:

```
$scope.$on 'new-fetch-controller:step-2', ->
  if EmailUtils.validate(self.contributorEmail)
    ToastService.show "Did you forget to add #{self.contributorEmail}?", 3
    self.addEmail(self.contributorEmail
```

Before - test looked like:

```
    beforeEach inject ($injector) ->
      mockService = $injector.get 'ToastService'

    it 'calls toast service on adding email', ->
      showSpy = @sinon.spy(mockService, 'show')        

      basics.contributorEmail = "test@test.com"
      newFetchScope.nextStep()

      expect(showSpy).to.have.been.calledWith("Did you forget to add test@test.com?", 3)
```

After, controller looks like (note the call to ToastService is now in a promise's then):

```
 $scope.$on 'new-fetch-controller:step-2', =>
  if EmailUtils.validate(@contributorEmail)
    $translate('fetches.new.contributors.auto_added', {email: @contributorEmail}).then (translation) ->
      ToastService.show translation, 3

    @addEmail(@contributorEmail)
```

The test now fails with:

```
Failure/Error: expected show to have been called at least once, but it was never called
```

How can I fix up my test?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the test like this:

1. I assign the $translate service to a variable in the controller, so I can later replace it with a fake service:

   @translate = $translate
2. Then I replace it with a fake translate service which returns a resolved promise and call scope.$apply() before expecting any results (note: 'basics' is my controller-as scope alias):

   ```
   it 'calls toast service on adding email', ->
     basics.translate = (key) ->
       deferred = $q.defer()
       deferred.resolve('some translation')

     deferred.promise

     showSpy = @sinon.spy(mockService, 'show')

     basics.contributorEmail = "test@test.com"
     newFetchScope.nextStep()
     newFetchScope.$apply()

     expect(showSpy).to.have.been.calledWith('some translation', 3)
   ```

If anyone has an alternative solution or a general advice - please post your thoughts.